# read_csv read in categorical values?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, categorical-data

I was wondering if there was a way to read in Categorical values during the `read_csv()` process.

Normally you can do a convert after the fact with something like:

```
df.zone = df.zone.astype('category')
```

At this point the df takes up more memory and I'm looking for a way to reduce that.

I've tried things like:

```
parking_meters = pd.read_csv('parking_meter_data.csv', 
                             converters={'zone': pd.Categorical(), 
                                         'sub_area': pd.Categorical(), 
                                         'area': pd.Categorical(), 
                                         'config_name': pd.Categorical(),
                                         'pole' : str(),
                                         'longitude' : np.float(),
                                         'latitude' : np.float()
                                        })
parking_meters.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()
```

However categorical data needs an initialization argument of the actual data, which is in CSV file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try with `dtype`:

```
parking_meters = pd.read_csv('parking_meter_data.csv', 
                             dtype={'zone': 'category', 
                                         'sub_area': 'category', 
                                         'area': 'category', 
                                         'config_name': 'category'
                                        })
```